# how to get more than 100 results with the Bing Search API v7?

Tags: bing, bing-api

I'm iterating over pages to get all results for a given request to the Bing Search V7 API (`https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search`):

```
{'q': 'tiramisu', 'offset': 0}
{'q': 'tiramisu', 'offset': 50}
{'q': 'tiramisu', 'offset': 100}
```

I notice that after 50-100 results, nothing new is given. So in practice, we cannot get more than 100 results, even though the `totalEstimatedMatches` is much larger (38100000 for tiramisu).

Why? How to fix this?

Notes: Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-web-search/page-results):

- Even with different non-overlaping offsets, there can be duplicates (confirmed)
- There is a [maximum for `count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-web-search/page-results#count-values-by-api), which is 50 for web pages.
- This the same question as [How to get more than 50 results from Bing search API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541530/how-to-get-more-than-50-results-from-bing-search-api), but the other one was for Bing V1, 8 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Ronak suggests in [Unable to paginate through all bing API results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449584/unable-to-paginate-through-all-bing-api-results) is that this is due to the fact that the API is designed for human users, who typically never go beyond 2-3 search pages.